Как вернуть подпоследовательность переданной строки при помощи функции - генератора в python
я пытаюсь описать подобным способом
def all_variants(text):
    for j in text:
        yield j


a = all_variants("abc")
for i in a:
    print(i)

в моем решении просто выходит a b c, а нужно:
a
b
c
ab
bc
ABC


И в чём у вас проблема? Добавьте ещё один цикл с yield как вариант..

Явно рекурсия какая-то напрашивается.

У вас в примере подстроки (непрерывные куски), а не подпоследовательности. Для подстрок:
def all_variants(text):
    for l in range(len(text)):
        for r in range(l,len(text)):
            yield text[l:r+1]

или так, в том порядке, который у вас использован:
def all_variants(text):
    for size in range(len(text)):
        for l in range(len(text)-size):
            yield text[l:l+size+1]


Я бы +1 в слайс перенёс, всё экономия )  И порядок вывода другой чем в вопросе. Но так то хорошо.

@CrazyElf Да, вы правы, добавлю с нужным порядком

Спасибо большое!

@МарияЖуравлева Не забывайте про https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer
